# Error in map with 2 classes: "binary '<': 'const _Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator"

Tags: c++, error-handling, stdmap

I'm having a weird error while declaring this map:

```
std::map<LoggedUser, GameData> m_players;
```

I've looked at many possible solutions, but couldn't find anything that works. I can't find the problem that causes this.

The error:

> C2676 binary '<': 'const _Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Game (where the map is declared):

```
#pragma once

#include "LoggedUser.h"
#include "Question.h"
#include "GameData_struct.h"
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class Game
{
private:
    std::vector<Question> m_questions;
    std::map<LoggedUser, GameData> m_players;

public:
    void add_question(Question question);
    void add_into_m_players(LoggedUser logged_user, GameData game_data);
    Question getQuestionForUser(LoggedUser logged_user);
    bool submitAnswer(LoggedUser logged_user, std::string answer);
    void removePlayer(LoggedUser logged_user);
};
```

LoggedUser:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class LoggedUser
{
private:
    std::string _m_username;
    int id;
public:
    LoggedUser();
    LoggedUser(std::string username, int id);
    std::string get_username();
    int get_id();
};
```

GameData:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Question.h"

//Game data struct
struct GameData
{
    Question currentQuestion;
    unsigned int correctAnswerCount;
    unsigned int wrongAnswerCount;
    unsigned int averangeAnswerTime;
};
```

Question:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
//Question 
class Question
{
private:
    std::string m_question;
    std::vector<std::string> m_possibleAnswers;
public:
    std::string getQuestion();
    std::string getPossibleAnswers();
    std::string getCorrentAnswer();
};
```

Comment: `std::map` requires that its keys be less-than comparable. `LoggedUser` is not thus comparable, and so cannot be used as a key in a `std::map`

Comment: `std::map` is ordered based on key. To do that ordering, it needs keys to be comparable using `operator<`. For your own class, you need to provide this comparison yourself (you can use `= default` with C++20).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map` is a sorted container. It uses `operator<` by default to compare keys for sorting and matching (you can optionally specify your own comparitor to override this behavior).

The error message is complaining that your `LoggedUser` class does not implement an `operator<` for comparing the `map`'s keys.